# How do I fix "No OpenID Server found at https://steamcommunity.com/openid"

Tags: php, openid, steam

I'm trying to add a Steam login to my website but get this error

> No OpenID Server found at https://steamcommunity.com/openid

Here's the code I'm using.

```
require 'steamauth/steamauth.php';


if(!isset($_SESSION['steamid'])) {

    loginbutton(); //login button

}  else {

    include ('steamauth/userInfo.php'); //To access the $steamprofile array
    //Protected content

    logoutbutton(); //Logout Button
}
```

the other four files are located here https://github.com/SmItH197/SteamAuthentication under "steamauth"

Answer (score 0):

if the files are in the same folder you dont have to call the folder

remove the **steamauth** from your include

Comment: are you saying completely delete the steam auth folder?

Comment: No im not saying that you must delete the folder if you want to include something that is NOT in the same directory but a previous directory you must user de ../ to go back an folder